# WPF: Calling ICommand from Ancestor in Code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my MVVM Application i have the MainWindow which displays my child view in a ContentControl Element.
The MainWindow DataContext houses an ICommand which allows the child views to change the view:

```
public ICommand ChangePageCommand { get; }
private void ChangePage(object parameter)
{
    Type paramType = parameter as Type;
    if (paramType == typeof(Main))
    {
        ViewModel = new Main();
    }
}
```

The ICommand works great when im Calling it from the childs wpf like this:

```
<Button 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType {x:Type Window}}, Mode=OneWay}" 
    CommandParameter="{x:Type ViewModel:Main}">
       Connect to Process
</Button>
```

But now i want to call the ICommand from the ViewModel of the childview, because after clicking the button i need to execute some code and dependent on the result i want to ether change the window or display an error message.

I have tried a lot of searching on how to do this, but I could not find anything about calling an ICommand of an Ancerstor from code.
Maybe I'm looking at wrong and there is a different way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Declare another ICommand property in "*the ViewModel of the childview*" and bind it like `Command="{Binding VmChangePageCommand}"`. The command would of course somehow have to know the main view model in order to delegate to it.

Comment: As a note, instead of checking each type you pass to the command, just call `ViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(paramType);`

Comment: As Clemens said, the child ViewModel should have its own ICommand. There is some code missing to get the full picture. What exactly are `ViewModel` and `Main` in your code? Are you using RelayCommands? You could move the `ChangePage` implementation to a Controller class orchestrating the ViewModels and use Dependency Injection to inject the commands. Another possibility would be to use an event messaging mechanism.